# Seleccionar un valor por defecto en un elemento HTML <select> cuya opción está deshabilitada

Tags: html, html5

Mi código es:

```html
<select>
  <option value="" disabled>seleccione la marca</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

¿Cómo hago para que aparezca en el select  `seleccione la marca`, pero que no se pueda seleccionar?

Intenté con `disabled` pero no aparece.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518002/1983854

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Créditos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22033973/4092887

Prueba con esta código cambiando tu `option` así:

```
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">seleccione la marca</option>
```

Este es el resultado:

```html
<select>
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">seleccione la marca</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Usa la propiedad `selected` ya que `disabled` en realidad es para deshabilitar la opción:

```html
<select>
  <option value="" selected>seleccione la marca</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

o puedes realizar una combinación de ambas propiedades:

```html
<select>
  <option value="" selected disabled>seleccione la marca</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

---

Esta es la definición de las propiedades:

> **selected**: Especifica que una opción debe ser preseleccionada cuando la
>   página se carga
>
> **disabled**: Especifica que se debe inhabilitar una opción

Answer (score 3):

le pones al `select` el atributo `required` y al `option` "seleccione la marca" le quitas el atributo `disabled`

```
<select required>
  <option value="">seleccione la marca</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Personalmente, ésta es la mejor solución desde un punto de vista funcional porque impedirá que se envíe el formulario si no se ha seleccionado una marca, mientras que usando disabled, se va a poder enviar el formulario con el campo deshabilitado seleccionado.

Comment: Así es mi estimado, se dispara el required si no se seleccione la marca. Gracias