# Mantener el registro de un ComboBox en un formulario de editar

Tags: php, html

tengo un problema con un formulario de editar empleados, tengo un comboBox donde despliego los puestos que existen en un select, pero no logro que en este formulario de editar me ponga seleccionada la opción que tiene el registro solo se imprime como seria por defecto. anexo mi código, espero me puedan ayudar.

```
<?php
require_once("TipoEmpleado.php");
require_once("Empleado.php");
$elId=$_GET['id'];
$empleado = new Empleado();
$tipoEmpleado = new TipoEmpleado();
$listaTipo = $tipoEmpleado->mostrarTodos();
$imprimir=$empleado->mostrar($elId); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
            <title>Editar empleado</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>  
            <div>
                <form action="GuardarEditarTipoEmpleado.php" method="POST">
                    <?php foreach($imprimir as $emple){ 
                ?>
                    <div class="container">
                        <input name="txtId" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $elId; ?>" />
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtNombre"  required class="form-control" id="txtNombre" value="<?php echo $emple->NomEmpleado; ?>" /><br/>
                        <label>Nombre de usuario</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtNombreUsuario"  required class="form-control" id="txtNombreUsuario" value="<?php echo $emple->NombreUsuario; ?>" /><br/>
                        <label>Contraseña</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtContrasena"  required class="form-control" id="txtContrasena" value="<?php echo $emple->Contrasena; ?>" /><br/>
                         <label>Correo Electronico</label>
                        <input type="text" name="txtCorreo"  required class="form-control" id="txtCorreo" value="<?php echo $emple->Correo; ?>" /><br/>
                        <label>Puesto</label>
                        <select name="txtTipo" id="txtTipo">
                        <?php
                        foreach($listaTipo as $tipo){
                        ?>
                            <option><?php echo $tipo->NomTipoEmp; ?></option>   
                        <?php
                            }   
                        ?>
                        </select>
                        <button type="btn-guardar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button> 
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="">Regresar</a>
                    </div>
                        <?php
                }
                    ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes explicar un poco mas detallado que es lo que quieres conseguir o que es lo que no te funciona. no entendi muy bien si era que no te llegan los datos al select o ya en la base de datos cuando mandas el formulario no te llega lo que el usuario eligio

Comment: Hola, lo que no logro es que el comboBox me ponga la opción seleccionada que tiene el registro, solo se muestra como seria por defecto.

Comment: Si en tu registro tienes el valor, entonces deberias colocar una condicion que si encuentra el valor entonces que lo coloque en selected="true", esta pregunta te puede ayudar (https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48900/93052)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que comparar en el `for` por cada ciclo si la opción que va a imprimir con `echo` es igual a la opcion guadada en `$emple`. Cuando se cumple, entonces imprimir en el HTML la etiqueta "`selected`".

Otra cuestión es que no tienes en el `option` la etiqueta `value`, por lo que no se va a enviar nada.
Desconozco como se llama la columna que tiene el tipo_emp, pero asumí que se llamaría `$emple->Tipo_Emp`. La reemplazas por el nombre que estas usando para ese campo. Finalmente lo normal es que los option de HTML tengan un formato como este:

`<option value="ID_item">Descripcion_item</option>`

en el value va un ID y no la descripción.

```
foreach($listaTipo as $tipo){
    $selected = ($tipo->NomTipoEmp == $emple->Tipo_Emp) ? 'selected' : ''; # Operador ternario
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $tipo->NomTipoEmp; ?>" <?php echo $selected; ?> ><?php echo $tipo->NomTipoEmp; ?></option>   
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

con esto lo solucionas, ya que el envio del `select` no envia lo que ves, sino el `value="algo"`, por ende debes de poner lo visual y el valor, asi:

```
 foreach($listaTipo as $tipo){
   ?>
   <option <?php echo "value='$tipo->NomTipoEmp'"; ?>><?php echo $tipo->NomTipoEmp; ?></option>   
   <?php
   }   
   ?>
```

espero te sirva, y lo hayas entendido... **ReNiceCode...**